# Google sign in error React native expo app

Tags: react-native, expo, google-signin

I am new to RN. Here is the issue. I am trying to provide a sign in mechanism via google for an expo app. I have created a firebase app as per the expo docs here [Expo google signin doc.](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v32.0.0/sdk/google/)

I can see the client id there in the console of firebase and used in the React Native app.But i get an error like this 
[image: Error screenshot]

Here are codes that i used

```js
    import React from 'react'
    import {Google} from 'expo'
    import {Alert} from 'react-native'
    const clientId=ID
    export default async function logIn() {
       try {
           const{type,user}=await Google.logInAsync({
           clientId
          })
       }
       catch(e) {
        console.log('error',e)
       }
    }
```

Reproduced error link: [Expo snack link](https://snack.expo.io/BkoVYiKB4)

Comment: Should you be posting your clientId on SO?

Comment: i was testing the app and new to RN so i didn't know the seriousness.Btw did u ever face the issue in the question?

Comment: I haven’t implemented a google signin.